# Всплывающие окна Eclipse в KDE

Tags: linux, kde, ide, eclipse, java

Работаю в *Eclipse* в *KDE4*.

Не удается нормально растягивать всплывающие окна (*автокомплит*, *джавадок* и прочие): при нажатии на кнопку *растянуть* окно разворачивается куда-то за пределы экрана.

В виртуалках *винде* и *убунту (юнити)* такой проблемы не наблюдал.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в настройках на размер экрана/вьюпорта, скорее всего размер экрана у вас стоит больше чем реальный физический размер экрана